# Why does BASHPID change in here-strings

Tags: bash

Can somebody explain the following behaviour with a here-string, please?

```
$ echo "$SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"
1 0 18689 18689
$ cat <<< "$SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"
1 0 19078 18689
$ cat <<< "$SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"
1 0 19079 18689
```

The `BASHPID` is different from the shell PID in the here-string, and change each time, but I don't understand why.
The same happens in here-documents:

```
$ cat << EOT
> $SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$
> EOT
1 0 19096 18689
```

Surprisingly, `BASHPID` doesn't change in a command group:

```
$ { cat ;} <<< "$SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"
1 0 18689 18689
```

On the other hand, it changes in a subshell

```
$ (echo $BASHPID ; cat) <<< "$SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"
20465
1 1 20465 18689
```

while the here-string is supposed to expand in the current shell.

Note: my bash version is 4.3+

Comment: `no subprocess should be created` The subprocess is created for `cat`.

Comment: You may compare `cut -d' ' -f1- <<< "ignore $SHLVL $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID $$"` then enable builtin with `enable -f /usr/lib/bash/cut cut` then compare again.

Comment: There is no `/usr/lib/bash/` on my system (Ubuntu). what is your bash version?

Comment: I think my archlinux is doing them, try any of `/usr/lib*/bash`. Sample loadable builtins were installed with bash on my system. bash 5.1.0 .They are from [loadables](https://github.com/bminor/bash/tree/master/examples/loadables).

Comment: Ok. I deduce that the weird thing about `BASHPID` lasts for bash 5+ for external commands. I think it's about context resolution order.

Answer (score 1):

(Just guessing ...)

The behavior is similar to this:

```
# echo $$
35130
# echo $( echo $$ $BASHPID )
35130 88025
# echo $( echo $$ $BASHPID )
35130 88026
#
# # or
#
# echo $$ $BASHPID | cat
35130 88028
# echo $$ $BASHPID | cat
35130 88030
```

Apparently `$BASHPID` is not expanded at the same time as `$$`. According to `man bash`:

> *BASHPID*
>
> > Expands  to  the  process  ID of the current bash process.  **This differs from `$$` under certain circumstances**, such as subshells that do not require bash to be  re-initialized.

This implies `$BASHPID` is not expanded the time Bash parses the command line otherwise it'll be the same as `$$`. And in Bash source code there's a func `initialize_dynamic_variables()` (in file `variables.c`):

```
1905 static void
1906 initialize_dynamic_variables ()
1907 {
1908   SHELL_VAR *v;
1909
1910   v = init_seconds_var ();
1911
1912   INIT_DYNAMIC_VAR ("BASH_ARGV0", (char *)NULL, get_bash_argv0, assign_bash_argv0);
....
....
1924   INIT_DYNAMIC_VAR ("BASHPID", (char *)NULL, get_bashpid, null_assign);
1925   VSETATTR (v, att_integer);
....
```

As it shows, vars like `BASHPID` are called *dynamic variables*. I guess these vars are handled specially and are expanded in the last minute when it knows that no more sub-shell will be forked (the fork may be followed by `exec()`, e.g., to run external commands).

Comment: About the first half of you response: yes that's why we have `$$` and `$BASHPID`. Second, `BASHPID` is in fact a dynamic variable. It might get expanded at special moments, but why should it take the `cat` PID on the first place, since `cat` is not a subshell but a subprocess?

Comment: **This** refers to the variable itself, not the expansion. That quote means *When in a subshell, $$ and $BASHPID hold different values*.

Comment: @Edouard the subshell replaces itself with `cat` by calling `execve`, here-document and thus $BASHPID are expanded before that happens.

Comment: to run an external command, bash would first `fork()` and then `exec()` which replaces itself with the external command.

Comment: @oguz: you mean: bash forks, than the son expand `BASHPID` as its PID, then the son execve `cat`; therefore the behavior. Ok, but why isn't it the case for `{ cat ;} <<< whatever`?

Comment: @Ed there is a subshell there, the subshell that puts *whatever* into a temporary file, opens and redirects it to stdin by means of `dup2`, then unlinks the temporary file and calls `execve`.

Comment: @Ed In that case bash forks **after** the here-document is ready to go.

Comment: regarding `{ cat; } <<< $BASHPID` : "This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, **such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized.**" -- this implies bash may handles $BASHPID differently based on the context though its not clear to me when it requires bash to be re-init'ed.

Comment: for `cat <<< $BASHPID` i believe `$BASHPID` is expaned between `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: @oguz you mean the here-document is handled by the son in the case `cat <<< "whatever"` (perhaps as a shortcut) and by the father in the case `{ cat ;} <<< "whatever"`?

Comment: @Ed yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Thanks it's sounds clear to me now; it's a kind of border effect, also.

Comment: @py by *re-initialize* it means calling one of the exec family functions to spawn a new instance of bash, subshells don't need that since they are copies of the main shell.

Comment: @oguz yes maybe. I'm used to check `$BASHPID` to understand variables scope. Here is one funny application of our problem: `cat <<< "$((a=1))" ; echo "$a"` echoes `1` and nothing (`a` is set in a subshell), while `{ cat ;} <<< "$((a=2))" ; echo "$a"` echoes `2` and `2`. Not a best practice for setting a variable, but dangerous!